# How to display all object's values inside HTML tag using forEach instead of manually iterating over all values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

I have a [code snippet](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) in JS I'm altering. The original has an object called `rows` defined by:

```
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
    return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
    createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
    createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
    createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
    createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
    createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];
```

And displayed with

```
<TableBody>
  {rows.map((row) => (
    <TableRow key={row.name}>
      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
        {row.name}
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
      <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
      <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
      <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

I'm trying to move all the HTML into a function:

```
function my_rows() {
return rows.map((row) => (
    <TableRow key={row.name}>
        <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>
            {row.name}
        </TableCell>
        { Object.values(row).forEach(v => <TableRow align='right'>{v}</TableRow> )}
    </TableRow>
))
}
```

but my `forEach` gives back nothing...

1. How can this be achieved (this being "generating all the correct HTML tags for each value of the object `row`")?
2. Is this a good idea? (My thought was this: Have a python-flask server generating this `row` object, and let JS display the whole object, without knowing beforehand which and how much values this object has)

Comment: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything. You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: @devserkan basically yes, but I still can't make it look like the original code

Comment: I didn't understand the main issue here but in the original code there are multiple `TableCell`s but you are iterating for `TableRow`s in your second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forEach does modification in place and does not return a new array unlike map. Use map instead of forEach.

```
function my_rows() {
 return rows.map((row) => (
  <TableRow key={row.name}>
    <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>
        {row.name}
    </TableCell>
    { Object.values(row).map(v => <TableRow align='right'>{v}</TableRow> )}
  </TableRow>
 ))
}
```

Comment: This indeed helps, as now I can get an output, but it looks weird, unlike the original code...

Answer (score 0):

to put HTML code in JS and call it back you have to do this, if you want to load the html code when the page is being loaded you have to put the functions name in onload at body's tag like

`<body onload="myFunction();">`

and in JS you have to do this

```
      // you have to create a div to put the html code in it 
      var div = document.getElementById("ID");

      html =" <TableRow key={row.name}>"
      html += "<TableCell component='th' scope='row'>";
      html += "{row.name}";
      html += "</TableCell>";
      html += "{ Object.values(row).forEach(v => <TableRow align='right'>{v} 
      </TableRow> )}";
      html += "</TableRow>";

      div.innerHTML = html;
```